# multi-dimensional array from forminput

Tags: php, arrays, forms, multidimensional-array

I think my solution is in a multi-dimensional array, but how...

If i have the following (or similar) in a HTML form (simplified for example)

```
<select name="Postage[]" id="Unique-ID">
    <option value="1">Postage Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Postage Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Postage Option 3</option>
</select>
<input name="PostagePrice[]" id="Price-Unique-ID" value="" />

<select name="Postage[]" id="Unique-ID">
    <option value="1">Other Postage Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Other Postage Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Other Postage Option 3</option>
</select>
<input name="PostagePrice[]" id="Price-Unique-ID" value="" />

<select name="Postage[]" id="Unique-ID">
    <option value="1">Another Postage Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Another Postage Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Another Postage Option 3</option>
</select>
<input name="PostagePrice[]" id="Price-Unique-ID" value="" />
```

How do i get this stored into a PHP array (so i can later add it to my DB)
So far i have the below, but it is clearly not finnished

```
if (isset($_POST['Postage'])) {
  if (is_array($_POST['Postage'])) {
    foreach($_POST['Postage'] as $PostateID=>$PostageOption){
      // this is where i am tottally stuck
      // need to assosiate postageID with a Postage Option and a PostagePrice
    }
  }
}
```

Im sorry to sound dumb but i have not yet had the "Erika" moment with multi-dimensional array's

I would be grateful for any advice

Comment: any example of the result you want?

Comment: can you please clarify with an example output array that you would like returned?

Comment: 'Erika', is that a mondegreen for 'Eureka'?

Comment: This looks like a form for creating possible postage options, perhaps for a product, which implies a postage option doesn't have the same price for every product.  If im even half right, then the way you are trying to accomplish this doesn't look very optimal.  Tell us what you are trying to do and perhaps we can find you a simpler solution.

Comment: Yes Flosculus, you are more than half right! I am trying to do similar to how ebay do postage. so that "the user" can set postage per product and with a varying postage and with multiple postage options

Comment: why the -1.... if we all knew the answer they may as well close this site down. what may seem silly to one person may now be known by others... i wish i was like you and born with all the knowledge in the world...

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['Postage']` is not a multidimensional array. You can easily see it if you var_dump($_POST['Postage']); It's just an array of all the selected indexes in your selects:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "1"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "1"
  }
```

Here is what I input for testing:

[image]

And here I get the postages and associated prices, using a for loop:

```
<?php
$n = count($_POST['Postage']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i)
{
    print $_POST['Postage'][$i] . " " . $_POST['PostagePrice'][$i] . "<br>";
}
```

prints:

```
1 1
2 2
2 3
```

Comment: Thanks, and yes i am somewhat confused as to if this is a multidimensional array (i think the result may be multidimensional...). So how would i get the result to be "1 PostageOption1/24HourDelivery $5.00"? OR "2 48HourDelivery $3.00", etc

Comment: @Ford After you received the ids of the Postages, you need to their names and delivery time from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your array of inputs as below:

```
<?
//Let your inputs be Postage1, Price1, Postage2, Price2...
//Then your Received POST will be..
$_POST = Array(
            "Postage" => Array( 0 => 'Postage1', 1 => 'Postage2', 2 => 'Postage3'),
            "PostagePrice"=> Array( 0 => 'Price1', 2 => 'Price2', 3 => 'Price3')
            );
//Now, you can see that index 0 points to a price of POSTAGE and so on 1 and 2..

//Store corresponding values in an Array.
$store = Array();

foreach($_POST['Postage'] as $PostateID=>$PostageOption){
    $store[$PostageOption] = $_POST['PostagePrice'][$PostateID];
}

print_r($store);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?PHP
$final = array_combine($_POST['Postage'], $_POST['PostagePrice']);
?>
```

By this way, you will associate Postage and PostagePrice in this array.